# Adobe PDF Autozoom when Scrolling

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, scrolling, zoom

On one particular PDF document, there is this really annoying behavior. If I set the zoom to 'Fit Window Width', when I scroll down (either scrolling with up down keys or scroll wheel), the moment I change pages, the zoom automatically reverts to 'Fit one full page'. I can scroll up and down on one page with 'Fit Window Width', but as soon as Adobe recognizes I have changed pages, it automatically reverts to this setting. 'Fit one full page' is set when the PDF is opened. How can I get rid of this frustrating thing! This does not happen with any other PDF documents.

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro X.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was no option in my reader that would fix this issue. The only way I was able to fix this issue was to print the PDF as a PDF. Weird, but it got rid of whatever issues there were in the coding of that file. I was able to retain the bookmarks when printing (option before printing), which was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the view setting called "Fit to window width and enable scrolling." I have a button for it on my toolbar but you can also find it in the Page Display tools and preferences (Adobe Acrobat X Pro). Screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that doesn't work.